# ATSU AOC software for A320 - how to change mass units for OOOI msgs from LBS to KGS

Tags: airbus-a320, avionics

There are 2 A320 acft; one which transmits OOOI msgs with FOB in LBS and one with FOB in KGS.  We want to maintain records in KGS but since the values are auto-parsed into our ops software we have to change them manually each time for the acft that transmits in LBS.  I am not an AME.  I inquired with Honeywell - they said it's a simple change but they'll charge us > $10,000 for it.

Do any Avionics AMEs know how to copy the ATSU AOC software from 1 acft to the other (from the KG acft to the LB acft)?  Is it possible?